# Need to show different colors to the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons in UIAlertController iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I want to have 2 different colors to the OK and Cancel button on alert from UIAlertController.

Comment: i want that too!!!! But where to start ? How about some googling !!!!

Comment: `preferredAction` or `UIAlertActionStyle` isn't enough to focus the attention of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this.

```
UIImage *accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ok.png"];
[okButton setValue:accessoryImage forKey:@"image"];
[alertVC addAction:okButton];
```